# How to run script after page is fully loaded, without jquery, without placing script at bottom?

Tags: javascript

How do I detect if the page is fully loaded?

No jquery, and I don't want to place a script on the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [window.onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/DOM/window.onload) to *"detect if the page is fully loaded"* :

```
window.onload = function(){
   ...
}
```

But note the difference with placing the script at the bottom of the body, which would not wait for the page to be fully loaded but just to be [ready](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.readyState). If you want the equivalent of placing the script at the end of the body, use [the DomContentLoaded event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/DOMContentLoaded) :

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: Neither works. The script loads before some elements are there, and I'm getting 'null' when looking for them.

Comment: Is the code needing the elements inside the function ?

Comment: Could you give code describing the specific issue?

Comment: The above calls an init function, which in turn looks for the elements.

Comment: Aha I found the problem. My function is actually being called before the variable is defined, even though it's at the very top of the script. So thank you, got it working with the DOMContentLoader. (I usually use window.onload which has worked until now)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `window.onload` or `document.addEventListener` functions:

There are 4 possibilities (options 1 and 4 could have an e parameter too)

```
window.onload = function(){
    alert("Window loaded");
}
```

---

```
window.onload = myfunction;
function myfunction(){
    alert("Window loaded");
}
```

---

```
window.onload = function(){ myfunction("Window Loaded") };
function myfunction(message){
    alert(message);
}
```

---

Equivalent of jQuery `$(document).ready()` , meaning that the page is ready, and although not fully loaded, should be safe to manipulate.

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",
function(){
    alert("DOM Content Loaded");
}, false);
```

Comment: A problem with `window.onload` is that if you use it in two scripts, one of them will be erased by the other. Use `addEventListener` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by the following way

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   // Java Script Code
}, false);
```